# ¿Como evito que se oculte un elemento?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, web

Al hacer click sobre "Enviar formulario" me muestra un `div` indicando si se guardó correctamente o falta llenar algún campo, el problema es que al hacer click nuevamente sobre "Enviar formulario" este `div` desaparece sin haber hecho nada solo clickeo nuevamente sobre el botón y quiero que no desaparezca este elemento `div`.

Espero se haya entendido.

Aquí el `Html` y `php`

```
<div id="loader"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 offset-md-4">
          <div id="alerta-mal" class=""></div>
          <div id="alerta-bien" class=""></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 form_register col-md-4  bg-dark">
          <form  action="" method="post" id="form_agregar_producto" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
               <h5 class="text-center text-info">Formulario</h5>
               <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
                 <label for="nombre" class="text-white">Proveedor</label>
                 <?php 
                    $SqlSelect="SELECT codproveedor,proveedor  FROM proveedor WHERE estatus=1 ORDER BY proveedor";
                    $rselect=mysqli_query($db,$SqlSelect);
                    $r_proveedor=mysqli_num_rows($rselect);

                    mysqli_close($db);
                    

                   

                  ?>
                 <select name="proveedor" id="proveedor" class="form-control">
                  <?php 
                    if($r_proveedor>0){
                    
                      while($rsSelect=mysqli_fetch_array($rselect)){
                   ?>
                   <option value=" <?php echo $rsSelect['codproveedor']  ?>"><?php echo $rsSelect['proveedor']  ?></option>
                 
                 <?php 
                    }
                  }
                  ?>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="producto" class="text-white">Producto</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="producto" name="producto" placeholder="Nombre del producto" value="" >
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                <label for="precio" class="text-white">Precio</label>
                 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="precio" placeholder="Precio del producto" name="precio">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="cantidad" class="text-white">Cantidad</label>
                 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad del producto">
               </div>
               <div class="photo">
                  <label for="foto" class="text-white">Foto</label>
                  <div class="prevPhoto">
                  <span class="delPhoto notBlock">X</span>
                  <label for="foto"></label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="upimg">
                  <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto">
                  </div>
                  <div id="form_alert"></div>
                </div>
        
               <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mt-2 mb-3" id="submit_agregar_producto" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Enviar formulario</button>
        
           </form>
```

**Aquí el `jquery`**

```
$("#submit_agregar_producto").click(function (e) {
    

    if($('#proveedor').val() == '' || $('#producto').val()=='' || $('#precio').val()=='' || $('#cantidad').val()=='')
    {
        $('#alerta-mal').html('<p class="mal">Complete todos los campos</p>');
        $('#alerta-mal').toggle(1000);
        return false;
    }
    
    $('#loader').show();
   

    $.ajax({
        url:"agregar-producto.php.php",
        type:"post",
        dataType:"text",
        data:$('#form_agregar_producto').serialize(),
        success:function(re){
            console.log(re);
            re=re.trim();
            $("#loader").hide();
            /*if(re =='userExist'){
                $('#alerta-mal').html('<p class="mal">El nombre  ya existe ,ingrese otro</p>')
                $('#alerta-mal').toggle(1000);
            }*/

            if(re == 'errorDatos'){
                $('#alerta-mal').html('<p class="mal">Error al crear el proveedor</p>');
                $('#alerta-mal').toggle(1000);
            }
            if(re == 'save'){
                $('#loader').show();
                $('#alerta-bien').html('<p class="bien">Proveedor agregado correctamente</p>');
                $('#alerta-bien').toggle(1000);
                $('#loader').hide();
            }
            
            
        },
        error: function(re){
                $('#loader').hide();
               console.log("Error",r);
            }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes varios errores
pero por el que preguntastes se daba en la funcion `toggle` ya que al dar el primer `click` la funcion `toggle` lo mostraba pero al dar otro `click` la funcion `toogle` hara lo contrario que era ocultarlo.
de paso tambien me tome la molestia de corregir algunas cositas.

**en el html solo cambias:**

```
<div id="alerta-mal" class=""></div>
<div id="alerta-bien" class=""></div>
```

**por:**

```
<div id="alerta" class=""></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
 $("#submit_agregar_producto").click(function(e) {
     //previene el comportamiento por defecto
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($('#proveedor').val() == '' || $('#producto').val() == '' || $('#precio').val() == '' || $('#cantidad').val() == '') {
         $('#alerta').html('<p class="mal">Complete todos los campos</p>').show();
         $('#alerta').hide(2000);
         return false;
     }

     $.ajax({
         url: "test.php",
         type: "post",
         dataType: "text",
         data: $('#form_agregar_producto').serialize(),

         // se ejecuta antes de enviar la data
         beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loader').show();
         },
         success: function(re) {
             console.log(re);
             re = re.trim();
             /*if(re =='userExist'){
                 $('#alerta').html('<p class="mal">El nombre  ya existe ,ingrese otro</p>')
                 $('#alerta').toggle(5000);
             }*/

             if (re == 'errorDatos') {
                 $('#alerta').html('<p class="mal">Error al crear el proveedor</p>').show();
             }

             if (re == 'save') {
                 $('#alerta').html('<p class="bien">Proveedor agregado correctamente</p>').show();
             // limpia el formulario si se inserto correctamente
             $('#form_agregar_producto').trigger("reset");
             }

             $('#alerta').hide(2000);

         },
         error: function(re) {
             console.log("Error", r);
         },
         // se ejecuta sin importa si falla o no
         always: function() {
          $('#loader').hide();
        }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando `toggle()`, el cual oculta o muestra un elemento, en tu caso, cuando algo está mal. Simplemente muestralo cuando algo este mal, y en caso de que pase las comprobaciones, ocultalo:

```
if($('#proveedor').val() == '' || $('#producto').val()=='' || $('#precio').val()=='' || $('#cantidad').val()=='')
{
    $('#alerta-mal').html('<p class="mal">Complete todos los campos</p>');
    $('#alerta-mal').show(1000);
    return false;
}

$('#alerta-mal').hide(1000);
```